# Kinetic Theory Model

Tags: physics, bounce, vpython

Edit: I've now fixed the problem I asked about. The spheres were leaving the box in the corners, where the if statements (in the while loop shown below) got confused. In the bits of code that reverse the individual components of velocity on contact with walls, some elif statements were used. When elif is used (as far as I can tell) if the sphere exceeds more than one position limit at a time, the program only reverses the velocity component for one of them. This is rectified when replacing elif with simply if. I'm not sure if I quite understand the reason behind this, so hopefully someone cleverer than I will comment such information, but for now, if anyone has the same problem, I hope my limited input helps!

Some context first:

I'm trying to build a model of the kinetic theory of gases in VPython, as a revision exercise for my (Physics) degree. This involves me building a hollow box and putting a bunch of spheres in it, randomly positioned throughout the box. I then need to assign each of the spheres its own random velocity and then use a loop to adjust the position of each sphere with reference to its velocity vector and a time step.

The spheres should also undergo elastic collisions with each wall and all other spheres.

When a sphere meets a wall in the x-direction, its x-velocity component is reversed and similarly in the y and z directions.
When a sphere meets another sphere, they swap velocities.

Currently, my code works so far as creating the right number of spheres and distributing them randomly and giving each sphere its own random velocity. The spheres also move as they should, except for collisions. The spheres should all stay inside the box as they should bounce off all the walls. They appear to be bouncing off each other, however, occasionally a sphere or two will go straight through the box.

I am extremely new to programming and I don't quite understand what's going on here or why it's happening but I'd be very grateful if someone could help me.

Below is the code I have so far (I've tried to comment what I'm doing at each step):

```
##########################################################
# This code is meant to create an empty box and then create
# a certain number of spheres (num_spheres) that will sit inside
# the box. Each sphere will then be assigned a random velocity vector.
# A loop will then adjust the position of each sphere to make them
# move. The spheres will undergo elastic collisions with the box walls
# and also with the other spheres in the box.

##########################################################

from visual import *
import random as random
import numpy as np

num_spheres = 15 

fps = 24 #fps of while loop (later)

dt = 1.0/fps #time step

l = 40 #length of box

w = 2 #width of box

radius = 0.5 #radius of spheres

##########################################################
# Creating an empty box with sides length/height l, width w

wallR = box(pos = (l/2.0,0,0), size=(w,l,l), color=color.white, opacity=0.25)
wallL = box(pos = (-l/2.0,0,0), size=(w,l,l), color=color.white, opacity=0.25)
wallU = box(pos = (0,l/2.0,0), size=(l,w,l), color=color.white, opacity=0.25)
wallD = box(pos = (0,-l/2.0,0), size=(l,w,l), color=color.white, opacity=0.25)
wallF = box(pos = (0,0,l/2.0), size=(l,l,w), color=color.white, opacity=0.25)
wallB = box(pos = (0,0,-l/2.0), size=(l,l,w), color=color.white, opacity=0.25)

#defining a function that creates a list of 'num_spheres' randomly positioned spheres
def create_spheres(num):
    global l, radius
    particles = []  # Create an empty list
    for i in range(0,num): # Loop i from 0 to num-1
        v = np.random.rand(3)
        particles.append(sphere(pos= (3.0/4.0*l) * (v - 0.5), #pos such that spheres are inside box
                            radius = radius, color=color.red, index=i))
        # each sphere is given an index for ease of referral later
    return particles

#defining a global variable = the array of velocities for the spheres
velarray = []

#defining a function that gives each sphere a random velocity
def velocity_spheres(sphere_list):
     global velarray
     for sphere in spheres:
        #making the sign of each velocity component random
        rand = random.randint(0,1) 
        if rand == 1:
            sign = 1
        else:
            sign = -1

        mu = 10 #defining an average for normal distribution
        sigma = 0.1 #defining standard deviation of normal distribution

        # 3 random numbers form the velocity vector
        vel = vector(sign*random.normalvariate(mu, sigma),sign*random.normalvariate(mu, sigma),
                 sign*random.normalvariate(mu, sigma))

        velarray.append(vel)


spheres = create_spheres(num_spheres) #creating some spheres
velocity_spheres(spheres) # invoking the velocity function

while True:
    rate(fps)

    for sphere in spheres:
        sphere.pos += velarray[sphere.index]*dt
        #incrementing sphere position by reference to its own velocity vector

        if abs(sphere.pos.x) > (l/2.0)-w-radius:
            (velarray[sphere.index])[0] = -(velarray[sphere.index])[0]
            #reversing x-velocity on contact with a side wall

        elif abs(sphere.pos.y) > (l/2.0)-w-radius:
            (velarray[sphere.index])[1] = -(velarray[sphere.index])[1]
            #reversing y-velocity on contact with a side wall

        elif abs(sphere.pos.z) > (l/2.0)-w-radius:
            (velarray[sphere.index])[2] = -(velarray[sphere.index])[2]
            #reversing z-velocity on contact with a side wall

        for sphere2 in spheres: #checking other spheres
            if sphere2 != sphere:
                #making sure we aren't checking the sphere against itself

                if abs(sphere2.pos-sphere.pos) < (sphere.radius+sphere2.radius):
                    #if the other spheres are touching the sphere we are looking at

                    v1 = velarray[sphere.index]
                    #noting the velocity of the first sphere before the collision

                    velarray[sphere.index] = velarray[sphere2.index]
                    #giving the first sphere the velocity of the second before the collision
                    velarray[sphere2.index] = v1
                    #giving the second sphere the velocity of the first before the collision
```

Thanks again for any help!

Comment: don't simply reverse the speed component of the particles, place them inside the box as well - for example simply clamp the position of the particle inside the box (reduced by twice the radius of the sphere). if you want full elastic bounces, you'd need to compute all points of collision for each particle and each wall per step, take the first collision, move the particle there, fix its velocity, recompute collisions for the remainder of the step, ect...

Comment: I actually realised what was going wrong and have now corrected it, thanks anyway though

Comment: Certainly, my apologies for not following protocol!

Answer (score 1):

The elif statements within the while loop in the code given in the original question are/were the cause of the problem. The conditional statement, elif, is only applicable if the original, if, condition is not satisfied. The circumstance wherein a sphere meets the corner of the box satisfies at least two of the conditions for reversing velocity components. This means that, while one would expect (at least) two velocity components to be reversed, only one is. That is, the direction specified by the if statement is reversed, whereas the component(s) mentioned in the elif statement(s) are not, as the first condition has been satisfied and, hence, the elif statements are ignored.

If each elif is changed to be a separate if statement, the code works as intended.